# NumPy linalg.eigh is returning incorrect eigenvectors

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I'm using NumPy's linear algebra package to calculate the eigenvectors corresponding to the minimum eigenvalue of large Hermitian matrices. The `linalg.eigh` function claims to return the eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix in ascending order, as well as the corresponding eigenvectors. This is precisely what I need. However, it seems that this function is failing even in the simple case of an already diagonal matrix. For example:

```
import numpy as np

H = np.diag([-0.4,-0.5, 0.4, 2.3, -0.5, -0.6, 0.3, 2.2, 0.4, 0.3, 1.2, 3.1, 2.3, 2.2, 3.1, 5.])
np.linalg.eigh(H)
```

The output is

```
(array([-0.6, -0.5, -0.5, -0.4,  0.3,  0.3,  0.4,  0.4,  1.2,  2.2,  2.2, 2.3,  2.3,  3.1,  3.1,  5. ]),
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]]))
```

i.e. the function outputs [0,0,0,1,...] as the eigenvector corresponding to -0.6, which is clearly untrue. Can anybody tell me why this function is failing?

Comment: Are you sure you don't just need to transpose that result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the NumPy documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html .

The eigenvectors are returned as columns of the output array, not the rows. You'll see that v[:,0] is the eigenvector corresponding to -0.6. If you transpose the result you can convert the eigenvectors to be in a row format.